# Showing All Messages Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKShareDialog

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

```
Showing All Messages
Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'FBSDKShareKit'


Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKShareLinkContent


Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKShareDialog
```

[image]

I have a little problem when using Facebook share SDK

Bellow is my frameworks settings and code

[image]

[image]

Comment: I solved it, it was the package I introduced that had a problem